# The relevant error-causing widget was StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart-null-safety, stream-builder

I am trying to find the solution for this error, help!
how can i solve this ?
i use this to make a chat app using firebase
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform
The relevant error-causing widget was
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>

```
import 'package:chat_app/Widgets/chat_bubble.dart';
import 'package:chat_app/constant.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

import '../models/message.dart';

class ChatPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static String id = 'ChatPage';

  CollectionReference messages =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(KMessagesCollection);
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: messages.snapshots(),
      builder: ((context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          List<Message> messagesList = [];
          for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data!.docs.length; i++) {
            messagesList.add(Message.fromJason(snapshot.data!.docs[i]));
          }
          
          
          return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
                title: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          Klogo,
                          height: 50,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text('Chat'),
                  ],
                ),
                centerTitle: true,
              ),
              body: Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: messagesList.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return ChatBubble(
                              message: messagesList[index],
                            );
                          }),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: controller,
                        onSubmitted: (data) {
                          messages.add({
                            'message': data,
                          });
                          controller.clear();
                        },
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Send Message',
                          suffixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.send,
                            color: kPrimaryColor,
                          ),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                          ),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: kPrimaryColor),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ));
        } else {
          return Text('Loading...');
        }
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error might occur inside the Message.fromJson() constructor. There might be a field you forgot or a typo. Check if all fields in the constructor match your fields in Firebase exactely.